# Error messages when installig wine

Tags: wine

When I tried to install wine on my computer, when I ran the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
```

I got an error message that said the following:

```
E: The repository 'http://build.openvpn.net/debian/openvpn/stable disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I also tried using this command:

```
sudo apt install wine-stable
```

But I got another error message:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

(I am a Linux beginner, so I don't know that much about the OS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to ask Ubuntu,

can you show your the full content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the full content in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`? In the first should only stored Ubuntu packages. In `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` you add extra PPAs. For example `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/projectatomic-ubuntu-ppa-focal.list` with this content: deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/projectatomic/ppa/ubuntu focal main

Use the edit button in your first entry.
Did you tried `sudo dpkg --configure -a`? If yes, what was the output?

Comment: I think I fixed it, thank you though for the feedback. God bless you!

Comment: No problem. You could accept my hint as your favorite solution.